# Binding to custom MVVM control

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, windows-phone-8.1, inotifypropertychanged

I have Custom User Control which uses MVVM :INotifyPropertyChanged. My app also uses MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged, but when I try to bind value to custom user control, app fails.

"Exception Failed to assign to property '%0'."

I need to use TwoWay Binding. Thank you for help.

Custom User Control

```
    private double _value = 0;
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Binding to element:

```
    private double _startMinutes;
    public double StartMinutes
    {
        get
        {
            return _startMinutes;
        }
        set
        {
            _startMinutes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StartMinutes");
        }
    }

    <controls:RadialSlider
        Value="{Binding StartMinutes}"
    />
```

Comment: I don't see a property called `StartMinutes` in that code, just `Value`. The mismatch will cause issues.

Comment: No, I updated question with StartMinutes value which is declared in MVVM of application.

Comment: You don't have a `Value` DP on the user control? Does that even compile? If you have one, the backing property would likely conflict with the posted one.

Comment: I don't use DP, I tried, but then value was not changing. How should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just bind to a normal property.

Binding is done through a `DependencyProperty`. The quickest way to make one is through the `propdp` snippet. They look like:

```
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(RadialSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Now your binding will work as expected. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/cc221408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more

Comment: Unfortunately, the same exception is thrown "Exception Failed to assign to property '%0'."

Comment: @bojo Is there *any* other information? Any System.Data exceptions above it? I don't have enough information to make any other recommendations.

Comment: Please, edit your answer. Value should be set with this method        private void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String p = null)
        {
            SetValue(property, value);
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        } and also data context of the usercontrol should be set like this (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;

Comment: @bojo I appreciate the input, but your first method *shouldn't* be necessary, as your DPs shouldn't be raising PropertyChanged. Your "DataContext" line indicates why this is so, you shouldn't *ever* set a view's data context to the code behind. The DataContext should always be in the view model. I don't want to encourage poor practice in my answer, so I would like to clear this up before editing.